# Make a relative positioned 100% height div in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a sidebar on the left hand side of the page with the content to the right of it. the problem I'm running into is that when I try to make the div 100% height, I have to set it to position: absolute; which causes the content to overlap the sidebar.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="sidebar col-sm-3">
    <ul>
      <li class="active">
        <h3><a href="">Link</a></h3>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <h3><a href="">Link</a></h3>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <h3><a href="">Link</a></h3>
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        <h3><a href="">Link</a></h3>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- sidebar -->
  <div class="sidebar-content col-sm-9">
    <ul>
      <li class="active">
        <h2 class="underline">Link</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum nostrum assumenda sequi praesentium aperiam. Accusamus omnis velit quos sint quas corporis inventore, facilis laborum pariatur explicabo maxime voluptas at aliquid!</p>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <h2 class="underline">Link</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum nostrum assumenda sequi praesentium aperiam. Accusamus omnis velit quos sint quas corporis inventore, facilis laborum pariatur explicabo maxime voluptas at aliquid!</p>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <h2 class="underline">Link</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum nostrum assumenda sequi praesentium aperiam. Accusamus omnis velit quos sint quas corporis inventore, facilis laborum pariatur explicabo maxime voluptas at aliquid!</p>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <h2 class="underline">Link</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum nostrum assumenda sequi praesentium aperiam. Accusamus omnis velit quos sint quas corporis inventore, facilis laborum pariatur explicabo maxime voluptas at aliquid!</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- sidebar-content -->
</div>
<!-- row -->
```

And my CSS

```
.sidebar {
background: #eee;
height: 100%;
padding-top: 100px !important;
}

.sidebar-content ul li {
display: none;
}

.sidebar-content ul li.active {
display: block;
}

.sidebar-content {
position: relative;
right: 0;
padding: 100px;
}
```

Can anybody tell me how to make the div relative and 100% height or a better way to go about creating a sidebar?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3Lapzoyf/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Add a `height` of `100vh` (which is a length unit representing 1% of the viewport height). This will result in a sidebar that has a `height` of `100%` of the viewport height. Also make sure you have your row(s) inside a `.container` or `.container-fluid` when you are using Twitter Bootstrap (if you didn't do that already).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="sidebar col-sm-3">
        <ul>
          <li class="active">
            <h3><a href="">Link</a></h3>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <h3><a href="">Link</a></h3>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <h3><a href="">Link</a></h3>
          </li>
          <li class="active">
            <h3><a href="">Link</a></h3>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- sidebar -->
      <div class="sidebar-content col-sm-9">
        <ul>
          <li class="active">
            <h2 class="underline">Link</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum nostrum assumenda sequi praesentium aperiam. Accusamus omnis velit quos sint quas corporis inventore, facilis laborum pariatur explicabo maxime voluptas at aliquid!</p>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <h2 class="underline">Link</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum nostrum assumenda sequi praesentium aperiam. Accusamus omnis velit quos sint quas corporis inventore, facilis laborum pariatur explicabo maxime voluptas at aliquid!</p>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <h2 class="underline">Link</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum nostrum assumenda sequi praesentium aperiam. Accusamus omnis velit quos sint quas corporis inventore, facilis laborum pariatur explicabo maxime voluptas at aliquid!</p>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <h2 class="underline">Link</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum nostrum assumenda sequi praesentium aperiam. Accusamus omnis velit quos sint quas corporis inventore, facilis laborum pariatur explicabo maxime voluptas at aliquid!</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- sidebar-content -->
  </div><!-- row -->
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.sidebar {
  background: #eee;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 100px;  
}

.sidebar-content ul li {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar-content ul li.active {
  display: block;
}

.sidebar-content {
  padding: 100px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
}
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/3Lapzoyf/4/